# Selenium: ElementClickInterceptedException occurs because of WebPack iframe in Angular application (even when using WebDriverWait)

Tags: c#, angular, selenium-webdriver, webpack

I had a bit of automation code that was stable for the longest time, and suddenly it was throwing an ElementClickIntercepted exception when clicking the "Sign In" button in the login screen:

```
public class LoginPage
{
    private readonly IWebDriver driver;
    private readonly WebDriverWait wait;

    private IWebElement UsernameElement => driver.FindElement(By.Id("username"));
    private IWebElement PasswordElement => driver.FindElement(By.Id("password"));

    public LoginPage(IWebDriver driver)
    {
        this.driver = driver;
        wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
    }

    public void LogIn(string username, string password)
    {
        wait.Until(d => UsernameElement.TypeText(username));
        wait.Until(d => PasswordElement.TypeText(password));

        var button = wait.Until(d => d.FindButtonByText("Sign In"));

        button.Click(); // <-- ElementClickInterceptedException thrown here

        wait.Until(d => !d.Url.Contains("/signin"));
    }
}
```

I had literally just be using the application under test and was able to log in just fine. It was maddening that the automated tests were failing now. Specifically it was mentioning an `<iframe>` whose Id had something to do with WebPack. My automated tests are running headless:

```
// appsettings.json in my test project set { Selenium: { Headless: true } }

var runInHeadlessMode = string.Equals(configuration["Selenium:Headless"], "true", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
var options = new ChromeOptions();

options.AddArgument("--ignore-ssl-errors=yes");
options.AddArgument("--ignore-certificate-errors");

if (runInHeadlessMode)
{
    options.AddArgument("--headless");
}

var driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

if (!runInHeadlessMode)
{
    driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
}
else
{
    driver.Manage().Window.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1280, 960);
}

return driver;
```

When running the application in a regular web browser, no such "iframe" was visible, and the page was fully interactable. I even used `wait.Until(d => d.FindButtonByText("Sign In").Click());` and that threw a WebDriverTimeoutException.

Answer (score 0):

I spent quite a while debugging this. Thankfully I was taking screenshots of the test failure:

[image: Screenshot of Angular screen showing TypeScript compilation problems from a Selenium test running in headless mode.]

Yup, a TypeScript compilation error was throwing up a "Compiled with problems" screen in my Angular application. Even more vexing, I had literally just been using the application. I had previously started the frontend using `npm run start`, and then proceeded to furiously switch branches in Git as I pulled the latest from master.

Fixing this was dead easy, and the only reason I'm posting this here is because I spent a long time figuring this out due to the tests running in headless mode.

**Kill and then restart the frontend.**

A good ol' <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> and then re-executed `npm run start` did the trick. Then frontend compiled and started with no problems. Now tests are passing.

I keep forgetting that Node doesn't seem to handle quickly switching branches very gracefully.